# How to access list of text of child node of li element using selenium in c#

Tags: c#, list, selenium-webdriver, dom, xpath

Having issues accessing the child node of a li element. Looking to print out all text within a list (which acts as a dropdown on the webpage). But all of the text is within an li element under an a> (the third a> tag) tag.

Here is an example of the DOM structure that I am trying to work with. This was given to me and I have no room to change it.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-mobile">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li data-ng-show="!vm.inIdentity" class="dropdown width-250 
             open">
                <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle ng-binding" data- 
                 toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                    <i class="icon-database position-left"></i> Select a 
                    repository <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu width-250 overflow-auto" 
                 style="max-height: 500px">
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Repositories</li>
                    <!-- ngRepeat: repository in vm.repositories --><li 
                     data-ng-repeat="repository in vm.repositories" 
                      class="ng-scope" style="">
                        <a href="" data-ng- 
                        click="vm.selectRepository(repository)" 
                        class="ng- 
                        binding"><i class="icon-database4"></i> **Akzo 
                        Nobel**</a>
                    </li><!-- end ngRepeat: repository in vm.repositories 
                          --><li data-ng-repeat="repository in 
                           vm.repositories" class="ng-scope">
                        <a href="" data-ng- 
                        click="vm.selectRepository(repository)" 
                        class="ng-binding"><i class="icon-database4"></i> 
                        AltAir Paramount</a>
                    </li><!-- end ngRepeat: repository in vm.repositories 
                    -->


       IWebElement dropdown = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//* 
           [@id='navbar-mobile']/ul[1]/li[1]/ul/li[2]/a"));

        Console.WriteLine(dropdown.Text);
        IList <IWebElement> ele = 
        dropdown.FindElements(By.XPath("//li"));


        foreach (var li in ele)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(li.Text);

        }//end foreach loop
```

I am expecting the values to print out. Values such as "Akzo Nobel", "AltAir Paramount" etc. Which are located under the li elements and a> tags. But for some reason I am only able to see the text of "Select Repository" in the debugger window.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by copying the DOM for the actual website and then from there going to paste on notepad++ and saving the file as .html. I saved it on my desktop and then in selenium called the url (the url that was generated by saving it as a html file in chrome).   In my code instead of using the original url (which is a private url) I would then use the new HTMl url that was generated. And I used this code to then fetch the text values that were in a> element under li element.

Comment: IWebElement dropdown = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@id,'navbar-mobile')]"));
            var ele = dropdown.FindElements(By.XPath("//i[contains(@class,'icon-database4')]"));
            foreach (var li in ele)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(li.Text);
              }

Comment: The thing is that this code only works for the newly created HTML file that was created not the private url or the actual website. When I try to apply it to the actual website it shows as a empty string text in the debugger view.